# how do i save playstore install application id?

Tags: android

in my application i m giving user a search buton to search app from googleplay store and save that application name in database    so i write playstore url in my code 
so when user open playstire is find any product and install i just want to save that eproduct id save in database how do i do that
? how i save only sepcific item from url??

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

When user click this button playstore open suppose user searcj a product and install which url is this

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun2&    
feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5pbWFuZ2kudGVtcGxlcnVuMiJd
```

How do i save only id form this ul to database  which is `id=com.imangi.templerun2`

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Check out this section of the android training guide: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: no no i knw how to save in database just tel me what ever application user install from app store how do i save is id in database? how to diffrenciate Id from url

Comment: how to get app id on run time?? i dontg know what app user install from app store i just want to save that application id in database how do i get application id which user install form app store

Comment: you can get the request param value of id from request parameter map.. It should be straight forward.

Comment: you can use splitter as in answer below, or use regex. There are many ways of doing this

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun2&    
feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5pbWFuZ2kudGVtcGxlcnVuMiJd";

String[] splited =  url.split("&");
String[] id = splited[0].split("?id=");
// your id[1] will equal = com.imangi.templerun2
```

Comment: the problem is i dont know what app user wants i just give weburl in button click which is  https://play.google.com/store/apps"  so browser will oepn so suppose user install any ap how do i save that ap id in my database i knowhow to insert in database just tell me how to i get that application id form url that user install

Comment: ur tricvk is little helping me but how  i do that? im just give this url  https://play.google.com/store/apps"    and web url will oepn how do i get id form that webpage?

Comment: how do i save url? bcoz when user click on this url  play.google.com/store/apps  app store open so how i save this url  "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun2&    
feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5pbWFuZ2kudGVtcGxlcnVuMiJd"

Comment: this [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-activity-and-browser-callback) will help you ..