# how to split url when browsing i want only specific value form url

Tags: android

This is my code which displays current webpage url. The code works fine but i want to get only specific value from url.

I follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260295/how-do-i-save-playstore-install-application-id) but is not helping me. Code is blast when run. I want only *Id* when browsing [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eamobile.monopoly_row_wf&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLmVhbW9iaWxlLm1vbm9wb2x5X3Jvd193ZiJd)

```
    public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] splited =  url.split("&");
            String[] id = splited[0].split("?id=");
            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), id.toString(), 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        // this is example url i just want to get only id from which url
        //https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eamobile.monopoly_row_wf&feature
        //=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLmVhbW9iaWxlLm1vbm9wb2x5X3Jvd193ZiJd

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didnt understand you. What is your issue??

Comment: i want to showin toast only id part of url suppose this is url
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eamobile.monopoly_row_wf&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLmVhbW9iaWxlLm1vbm9wb2x5X3Jvd193ZiJd   i want to show in toast only this part id=com.eamobile.monopoly_row_wf

Comment: actully i want to show only id of any application which user browse so url is too long i just want to show only that application id like com.eamobile.monopoly_row_wf

Comment: and currently what is it showing...

Comment: @HayyaAnam : hi hayya. means you only want to extract id from current URL?

Comment: nothing show  when i just write this       Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
is show full url i want to split url but this split code not work application is blast when run this code

Comment: yesssssss i only want to extact id form url

Comment: i follow this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260295/how-do-i-save-playstore-install-application-id but is not help me code is blast when run this code how do i split??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment you would like to see `com.eamobile.monopoly_row_wf`

Hence the code for that is

```
 String standard = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
 String id= url.substring(standard.length(), url.indexOf("&"));
 Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), id.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
```